# Problem with simple orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I re-edit this because I saw the question was not clear enough:

I know it's a silly exercise but I'm having a problem in showing that the inverse $M^{-1}$ of a simple 2 x 2 orthogonal matrix coincides with its transpose $M^T$.

In other words given an orthogonal matrix $\;\begin{align} M =   \begin{pmatrix} u_1 & v_1 \\ u_2 & v_2 \\ \end{pmatrix} \end{align}$ using only the facts descending from its orthogonality:

1) $\begin{align} u_1^2+u_2^2 = 1 \end{align}$
2) $\begin{align} v_1^2+v_2^2 = 1 \end{align}$
3) $\begin{align} u_1v_1+u_2v_2 = 0 \end{align}$

(because by definition its two column vectors $\begin{align} \bar u = (u_1,u_2)^T \end{align}$ and $\begin{align} \bar v = (v_1,v_2)^T \end{align}$ are unitary and orthogonal ones) I have to show that $\begin{align} M^{-1}=M^T \end{align}$ proving it through

$\begin{align} M^TM=MM^T=I \end{align}$.

Thus  $\;\begin{align} M^T =   \begin{pmatrix} u_1 & u_2 \\ v_1 & v_2 \\ \end{pmatrix} \end{align}$ and computing $\begin{align} M^TM = \begin{pmatrix} u_1^2+u_2^2 & u_1v_1+u_2v_2 \\ u_1v_1+u_2v_2 & v_1^2+v_2^2  \\ \end{pmatrix} \end{align} $ is ok yielding the identity I because of 1,2 and 3 above.

The problem arises with $\begin{align} MM^T = \begin{pmatrix} u_1^2+v_1^2 & u_1u_2+v_1v_2 \\ u_1u_2+v_1v_2 & u_2^2+v_2^2  \\ \end{pmatrix} \end{align}$ which I cannot make to look as I.

***Edited again for more clarity***:

I have to prove that \begin{align} MM^T = \begin{pmatrix} u_1^2+v_1^2 & u_1u_2+v_1v_2 \\ u_1u_2+v_1v_2 & u_2^2+v_2^2  \\ \end{pmatrix} = I \end{align} (if my computation is not wrong) just using the above 1,2 and 3. In other words I have to prove that $u_1^2+v_1^2 = 1$, $u_1u_2+v_1v_2 = 0$ and so on.

In doing so, even if possible, I'm not supposed to use trigonometric identities or the classical inverse definition as somebody (and who I thank anyway for the tip) pointed out.
That's where I'm having trouble.

***Ok this is answered, thanks everybody.***

Crucial part of the right answer from Gerry Myerson and the rest easily worked out by me, see below (all comments too in case interested).

Comment: Write your orthogonal matrix $M$ in trigonometric form and use trig identities.

Comment: Ok I'll give a look at it. Thanks

Comment: Yet I would like to understand why I cannot make it work like it is.

Comment: What definition of orthogonal matrix are you using? A widely used definition is exactly that $M^{-1}=M^T$.

Comment: Exactly that one (as on wikipedia too http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthonormal_matrix), implying that u and v are the two unit and orthogonal column vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $\qquad\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad u_1v_1+u_2v_2=0$,
Multiply by $u_2$: $\qquad\qquad \qquad \qquad u_1u_2v_1+u_2^2v_2=0$,
Multiply by $v_1$: $\qquad\qquad \qquad \qquad u_1u_2v_1^2+u_2^2v_1v_2=0$,
Go back to first line and multiply by $v_2$: $u_1v_1v_2+u_2v_2^2=0$,
Multiply by $u_1$: $\qquad\qquad \qquad \qquad u_1^2v_1v_2+u_1u_2v_2^2=0$,
Add lines 3 and 5: $\qquad\qquad \qquad u_1u_2(v_1^2+v_2^2)+v_1v_2(u_1^2+u_2^2)=0$,
Apply given facts: $\qquad\qquad \qquad \qquad u_1u_2+v_1v_2=0$.

In short: multiply by $u_1v_2+u_2v_1$, and collect terms, recalling $u_1^2+u_2^2=v_1^2+v_2^2=1$.

Comment: Ok, wrapped all until LINE 5 --> LINE 6 .There was also division in LINE 3 --> LINE 4 so some sort of assumption must be made, I guess.

Comment: There is no division in line 3 to line 4; line 4 comes from line 1 by multiplication. Line 6 comes from adding lines 3 and 5.

Comment: Wow, and I thought I had experience in this! It could have taken me quite a while to come up with that as it is done without remarks and in the same line.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: Thanks very much it's very ingenious. Any idea about showing that $u_1^2+v_1^2 = 1$ or $u_2^2+v_2^2 = 1$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio: I though I was skilled too at basic algebra but it looks I'm not ;-)

Comment: My idea for showing the other ones is to study my answer until inspiration strikes.

Comment: @Gerry: I suspected so, in fact I'm trying... :-) Thanks

Comment: @Gerry: Ok, after your answer it was just a matter of minutes to make it. In fact since you proved that $u_1u_2+v_1v_2=0$ then it yields \begin{align}v_1=-\frac{u_2}{u_1}v_2\end{align} which can be substituted in $u_1v_1+u_2v_2=0$ giving \begin{align}u_1u_2-\frac{u_2}{u_1}v_2^2=0\end{align} and finally $u_1^2=v_2^2$. Substituing that in $\begin{align} v_1^2+v_2^2 = 1 \end{align}$ proves \begin{align} u_1^2+v_1^2 = 1 \end{align}. The other one is analogous. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The inverse of your matrix, by definition, is

$$M^{-1}=\frac1{u_1v_2-u_2v_1}\begin{pmatrix}v_2&\!\!-v_1\\\!\!-u_2&u_1\end{pmatrix}$$

As the above is to be your matrix's transpose, it must be that

$$u_1=\frac{v_2}{u_1v_2-u_2v_1}\;\;,\;\;v_1=-\frac{u_2}{u_1v_2-u_2v_1}\;,\;\;etc.$$

Use the above and get your matrix product as you want...

Comment: Thanks very much. I agree and see your point. Unfortunately I seek a different answer: I re-edited the question above to explain myself better.

Comment: I can't understand what "different answer" you may be looking for: you **already** know that $\;M^TM=I\iff M^T=M^{-1}\;$ , by existence and *uniqueness* of the inverse (which you know, I presume, is in the ring of square matrices iff it is a left (right) inverse). The above comes to explain how (since the why's already clear...) we *also* get $\;MM^T=I\;$ ...Perhaps you should also add what are you expecting to see in an "answer".

Comment: It's written in the question: I have to prove that \begin{align} MM^T = \begin{pmatrix} u_1^2+v_1^2 & u_1u_2+v_1v_2 \\ u_1u_2+v_1v_2 & u_2^2+v_2^2  \\ \end{pmatrix} \end{align}, if my computation is not wrong, is I (the identity matrix) just using the above 1,2 and 3. In other words that $u_1^2+v_1^2 = 1$, $u_1u_2+v_1v_2 = 0$ and so on. I edited the question again to make more clear. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @noob, yes: perhaps add this to your question, yet I'm not sure that **only** from those three points you can get what you want. In fact, I'm almost (almost...!) sure you need something *out* of those points...but who knows: I may be missing something basic here.

Comment: They should be enough since they are what makes the definition of orthogonal matrix. The first half of the proof ($M^TM$) is ok, only the second is not ($MM^T$).Thanks for your time.

Comment: I know *that*, @Noob, yes as I remarked before, I think one *must* use other things (as written: uniqueness of inverse = inverse from the left = inverse from the right and etc.) to deduce what you want.

Comment: @Don, see my answer.